# Passing variable user,pass,sid in sqlplus comman

Tags: bash, variables, oracle11g, command-line-arguments, sqlplus

I want to pass variables in sqlplus command in my bash script, answer might be given but doesn't work for me.

I tried some thing like this

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh oracle@10.116.12.26 <<XX
echo Please enter an Oracle Username:
read USERNAME

echo "Please enter the Oracle Username's Password:"
read -s PASS 

SID=XE

export conn_str=$USERNAME/$PASS@$SID

sqlplus $conn_str  << EOF
select * FROM tabs;

exit
EOF
XX
```

also tried

```
sqlplus $USERNAME/$PASS@SID            #with option -s  and -l
```

I also find solution like [this](http://www.dbsnaps.com/oracle/oracle-running-sqlplus-from-unix-bash-scripts/)
but not worked for me.

oracle : 11g
,os     : fedora 18

Is there any solution available for this ?
thanks.

Comment: 'Doesn't work for me' is not an error message. What happens? Is it legal to have a nested `herdoc` (`<<EOF` within `<<XX`)?

Comment: As commented by @AlexPoole, the problem is due to the nested `HEREDOC`.  Put the last line `XX` after `SID=XE`.

Comment: @devnull - that won't work, `sqlplus` would run on the local host then, not the remote host the `ssh` is to. It looks like the nesting is OK, which is a bit of a surprise.

Comment: @AlexPoole Ah! didn't realize that.  However, in the present case, it's trivial to get rid of the second heredoc.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what actually happens, but I'm guessing you aren't prompted for the credentials, and that maybe it can't find `sqlplus`. On a Red Hat box this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please enter an Oracle Username:
read USERNAME
echo "Please enter the Oracle Username's Password:"
read -s PASS
SID=XE
conn_str=$USERNAME/$PASS@$SID

ssh oracle@10.116.12.26 << EOF
# set these for your specific environment
ORACLE_HOME=<path to ORACLE_HOME>
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin # or without .../bin depending on client
TNS_ADMIN=<path to tnsnames.ora directory, if not default>

sqlplus -s /nolog
connect $conn_str
select * FROM user_tables;
exit
EOF
```

This is collecting the values from the user on the local machine to avoid the 'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal' issue.

It is then setting up the Oracle environment once on the remote server - what you need to set depends on which client you're using (particularly whether you're using the instant client, though if you're connecting as `oracle` that seems unlikely, and you can probably run `oraenv`).

I've also tweaked it to run SQL*Plus with `/nolog` and then `connect` once running, so the credentials aren't exposed in the `ps` output. And I've switched from the old `tabs` to the more common `user_tables`.

The nested heredocs work but aren't necessary; the SQL commands are already being entered in the right place and will be seen by SQL*Plus rather than the remote shell.

Of course, since I don't know what error you were actually seeing this is largely speculation. It would probably be simpler to have the client installed locally and use a SQL*Net connection rather than SSH, but there could be firewall restrictions we don't know about.

Comment: when i enter username & pass, it throws error like : Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: @krupal - OK, that should be a warning (from SSH) with my version, as it's getting the values locally. (Though I don't have a Fedora instance to try it on; doubt it's that different between Red Hat and Fedora though). Have you tried this version? Does something still not work?

Comment: given password is null "ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied"

Comment: @krupal - not sure, I don't see that; I guess you can display `$conn_str` to check the values while you're debugging it?

Comment: oracle user is not at remote host, it is in local machine, but when do <su - oracle> it doesn't stop for password

Comment: @krupal - it's still remote as far as `ssh` is concerned; but if it's the same machine, why change user at all, why not just use SQL*Plus as yourself?

Comment: because if i don't change to oracle user, shell prompts sqlplus: command not found

Comment: So set the environment variables - ORACLE_HOME, PATH, etc., - so you can pick it up. You can get the values from the `oracle` user. Unless you don't have permissions to reach it as yourself. Seems simpler to me, but the `ssh` route ought to work if you want to stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your here doc delimiter to prevent stale variable expansions on the local machine.

```
ssh oracle@10.116.12.26 <<'XX'
```